# Can't step into shared library, symbols not loaded

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, gdb, shared-libraries

I have an app that I have developed using QT Creator. The project builds and references a couple shared libraries that are in the build tree. When I try to debug my project using the remote debugger, I can't step into or break on any of the library code.

I have tried fixing it by setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, using `set-solib-search-path`, etc.

More detailed info:

- Host machine is a VM running Ubuntu 16.04
- Target machine is a BeagleBone Black running Jessie
- Everything is compiled as debug (with the -g flag)
- My executable is in `/home/debian`
- My library files are in `/home/debian/lib`

`ls $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` shows all of my library files, as expected

Start up command for GDB:
`set solib-search-path /home/debian/lib`

running `gdb /home/debian/lib/mylib.so.1` yields the following:

```
GNU gdb (Debian 7.7.1+dfsg-5) 7.7.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "arm-linux-gnueabihf".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from lib/mylib.so.1...done.
```

which implies that gdb is able to read the symbols.

However, running `info shared library` in the debugger console in qt yields

```
>~"From        To          Syms Read   Shared Object Library\n"
>~"                        No          /home/debian/lib/mylib.so.1\n"
```

Running `sharedlibrary /home/debian/lib/mylib.so.1` doesn't seem to do anything; it just says "done".

Running `add-symbol-file /home/debian/lib/mylib.so.1` fails with
`The address where /home/debian/lib/mylib.so.1 has been loaded is missing`

The application output screen says `"Could not load shared library symbols"` when it starts, and says `"Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?"` but `show solib-search-path` prints out 
`The search path for loading non-absolute shared library symbol files is /home/debian/lib.` as expected.

How can I resolve this so that I can debug my libraries?

**EDIT:**
If I debug on the target device, instead of remote debugging from Qt Creator, gdb can load the symbols, step into library code, and set breakpoints just peachily. Anyone have an idea as to why I can't remote debug?

Comment: You probably need to install the Debian package that provides the debugging symbols on your target machine. The name will vary depending on the exact library you are trying to debug. e.g. libqt5gui5-dbgsym for libqt5gui5 dependency.

Comment: @Hitobat, I am trying to debug a library that I wrote. Not a QT library

Comment: Ah my bad. I guess check you're not linking with `-s` or similar args for "stripped" mode? From your "info shared library" output it clearly says "Syms No" so it looks like you have no symbols there for whatever reason.

Comment: @Hitobat everything is as QT creator set it up, how can I check/specify that? In the compile output there are lines that say `ln -s mylib.so.1.0.0 mylib.so
ln -s mylib.so.1.0.0 mylib.so.1
ln -s mylib.so.1.0.0 mylib.so.1.0`, could this be my issue?

Comment: @Hitobat on another thread I read that if `readelf --debug-dump=line mylib.so` produces an output, the library contains debugging info. I ran the command and there's  definitely output

Comment: `file mylib.so.1.0.0` will tell you if it is stripped.

Comment: @stark, running the `file` command confirms that the library is not stripped. Thanks